# Difference between legen and hinlegen

Tags: difference, verb-choice

Looking at the WordReference dict entries for both, they seem pretty similar:

https://www.wordreference.com/deen/legen

https://www.wordreference.com/deen/hinlegen

I've been told that "legen" needs a location where something is put and "hinlegen" cannot be used with a location. Is that true? Examples:

> Soll ich das Tischtuch auf den Tisch legen?
> Wo soll ich das Tischtuch hinlegen?

Comment: @Roland I don't understand the difference between "im Wohnzimmer" and "auf den Tisch legen" regarding direction. Every time I lay something on top of something ("legen" in German), there is an implicit downward direction.

Comment: Well, "legen" is a directional verb. ("liegen" is the corresponding situational verb.) Of course, the verb already implies a downwards direction but you can be more specific (e.g., "auf den Tisch").

Comment: My point is that your first comment says that "auf den Tisch" implies direction and "im Wohnzimmer" not and I don't understand the latter, as IIUC both are places where the tablecloth will be laid on.

Comment: @Roland: Do not post answers as comments. It's impossible to downvote comments.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I agree with the content of your comment and I am thankful that you make users aware of this rule. However, I think the tone of your comment is quite rude. A more kind way to address the issue could be: "Please do not post answers as comments. It is against the whole logic of this site. Please also see https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/please-do-not-answer-a-question-in-a-comment" - same content but way friendlier.

Answer (score 2):

### legen

*Legen* means to bring something into a horizontal position.

> Martin **stellt** das Buch ins Regal, Erika **legt** das Buch auf den Tisch.
> Martin **puts** the book on the shelf, Erika **puts** the book on the table.

It's *"put"* in English in both cases, but *stellen* means, that the books ends uprights standing while *legen* means that is at the end the book is laying flat on the table.

### hinlegen

*Hinlegen* means the same, but the target of the movement is optional.

> Correct: Ich möchte das Buch auf den Tisch hinlegen.
> Correct: Ich möchte das Buch auf den Tisch legen.
> Correct: Ich möchte das Buch hinlegen.
> Wrong: Ich möchte das Buch legen.

---

Hinlegen can also mean laying down for sleeping.

> Correct: Ich werde mich mal kurz hinlegen.
> Wrong: Ich werde mich mal kurz legen.

When a Chicken lays an egg, it's always legen:

> Wrong: Das Huhn wird ein Ei hinlegen.
> Correct: Das Huhn wird ein Ei legen.

Same for fortune tellers who lay cards:

> Wrong: Die Wahrsagerin wird mir die Karten hinlegen.
> Correct: Die Wahrsagerin wird mir die Karten legen.

Comment: One thing I've noticed about German is that you normally don't say something "is" somewhere; it usually has to either "lie" (*liegen*) or "stand" (*stehen*) somewhere. Since *legen* is the causative of *liegen*, the same distinction seems to apply; you don't "put" something somewhere, but "lay" (*legen*) it, assuming it's going to "lie" there when you're done.

Comment: @RDBury: That's correct. In German you could also say *»Martin **gibt** das Buch ins Regal, danach **ist** es im Regal. Erika **gibt** das Buch auf den Tisch, danach **ist** es auf dem Tisch.«* (*Geben* is here not *give* but *put.*) But we usually don't. We have more specific vocabulary and when ever possible we use it. So, we prefer this version: *»Martin **stellt** das Buch ins Regal, danach **steht** es im Regal. Erika **legt** das Buch auf den Tisch, danach **liegt** es auf dem Tisch.«*